# Min/Max object coordinate values

Tags: mesh, coordinates

I need to find the min and max z height values from a mesh of a complex object and mark them red in the rendered photo of the objects. A small dot would suffice. The max/min are found along a line along x or y coordinate, but it is not necessary to draw the line:

[image]

I know some osl but that only allows to work with a single position and no memory of other points, as far a I know. It should be rendered with orthographic projection.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds complex. What have you tried? render engine? opengl? perspective or orthographic rendering? Please add more information to the question to get a solid answer.

Comment: "mark them red"  maybe share a representative screenshot and draw over it to help us understand what you mean.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. i am new to blender. I know some osl but that only allows to work with a single position and no memory of other points, as far a i know. It should be rendered with orthographic projection. Thanks

Comment: consider the concept of min/max, how do you want to mark it? a single pixel? a fat line? a painted area?

Comment: A small dot would suffice. The max/min are found along a line along x or y coordinate, but it is not necessary to draw the line.

Comment: And the new blue one?

Comment: That is for the minimum

Comment: are you trying to do this? local minima / maxima global minima / maxima ? http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Maxima_and_Minima.svg/650px-Maxima_and_Minima.svg.png

Comment: It should show all local and global extrema along a line.

Comment: Just to get it right, how about adding real geometry? http://i.stack.imgur.com/SGSBY.png, result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hMsYz.png

Comment: Not really, If you have a unit sphere with center at x=0, y=0, z=0 with the camera looking a distance in the z direction and you sculpt it to have bumps and valleys in the z direction, i would like to mark the highest and lower values of z in let's say the line with x = 0.4, with  red and blue dots respectively, such that when i render it in the image i can see the dots.

Comment: You can seperate the dots to a new render layer and add it on top of the rendering - see my result (dot below is added on top).

Comment: @user14641 please share a blend of one such representative object, making the correct visual will be less work for us http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The question is about calculating local maxima/minima. Is there a way for me to extract a profile of the object along some x? this does not mean get a wire from the wireframe or a set of vertices but actual height/depth values. Thanks

Comment: @user14641 I'm not very experienced with blender but: you can use compositing, click use_nodes, then write up your own new node whose image input #1 is the render layers Z channel, and image output is an image with the marked dots. Once your node is written, mix the output with a Mix node. The depth at each pixel will be available to you inside your node. You can reshape that into a numpy array, then find the maxima you want at a given x or y scanline. Next, you mark the found dots with RGB values at the output image.

Comment: @user14641 to just "extract a profile of the object along some x", add a Viewer node whose input is Render Layer's Z, then the pixels will be readily available in python as bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels. Reshape that into a numpy array of the right size then slice with a given x or y value.